Nox Android 7 (32-bit) Settings Reversion Issue on Prevps DE7 Machine
We are encountering an issue with our prevps DE7 machine.
The steps are as follows:

We create a Nox instance on the DE7 machine.
Configure settings such as enabling developer options.
Wait for the debugger to toggle off and set the selected app to "nothing."
Save the settings and shut down the Nox instance.
Upon reopening the app, the settings revert, and the app gets stuck on "waiting for the debugger."

It's worth noting that the same Nox instance works without issues on our DE3 machine. Also the app is released and has  false.
Could anyone please help us determine the root cause and guide us on how to ensure the settings are saved properly?
I have tried to clear cache, restart nox instance also created fresh instance still facing issue.

I assume that "DE7" and "DE3" are just names of different machines on your network.

If one is working but the other isn't, check that they are both running the same version of the software first. What versions of Nox are installed on these machines? Are they the same?
